# Why are different libraries searched for in tensorflow, even though both were installed the same way?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I built tensorflow from source and got a *.whl file that I could install on my pc with pip install *.whl. Now in the virtualenv where I installed it I can open python and do import tensorflow without a problem and also use tf. Now I tried to install this same wheel on an other pc in a virtualenv and it worked successfully, but when I try to use import tensorflow in python I get:

`ImportError: libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.390.48: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Now I actually do not have that file on the other pc, but after checking my own pc I also don't have it here. I have on both pcs libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.390.87. On both pcs the LD_LIBRARY_PATH points to the directory with that version.

How can it be that tensorflow searches for version 48 on the remote pc while searching for 87 and finding it on my pc, even though they are both installed with the same whl file? Is there a config that I need to adjust what version it should search for?

Comment: You have a broken cuda in one of your computers, that's why you get this error. run ldd on libcuda.so and you will see it tries to load the libnvidia-fatbinaryloader

Comment: Oh wow that is actually correct. I just assumed that cuda is installed correctly since it is a cluster and other people use it. This weirds me out, how can people even use this cuda version when libcuda has broken links weird. Thanks this helps me greatly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you have a broken CUDA installation somewhere in the library path. It is `libcuda.so` that has a dependency on `libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so`, so maybe the symbolic links point to a library that no longer exists but was installed before.

You can find this information by running the `ldd` command on the `libcuda.so` file.

Comment: Is there an easy way to make libcuda.so point to the proper fatbinaryloader? Since I don't have admin rights and I'm not sure if I can reinstall cuda is there a way to just make libcuda.so point to the right fatbinaryloader version? it can involve sudo, but the less commands the happier my supervisor will be

Comment: @Hakaishin Actually I would have this checked by a competent person, maybe reinstalling cuda completely helps. The problem is that I cannot give you a solution for which I haven't seen the status of the files in the computer. It can break even more things.

Comment: Actually reinstalling cuda did not fix the error. Any ideas what else one could do? Right now I could make a symlink from 48 to 87 but this sounds dangerous and could introduce subtle bugs right? Or is this a good solution?

Comment: @Hakaishin No, the symlinks aren't right, you can try regenerating them by running ldconfig as root.

Answer (score 0):

The building process is related to the computer environment.Could building tensorflow in the same machine and installing it on the same machine help?Building on one machine and generating the *.whl,but installing on other machines may cause problem.

Comment: Really? How come then build servers are a thing?

Comment: Maybe the servers have the same computer environments such as python,anaconda,CUDA version and so on.